# Stacked Horizontal Bars not in align Chart JS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to create Batsman Partnership chart for Cricket Matches.

I am trying to create stacked Horizontal Bars using Chart.js, but I am facing an issue that bars are not getting aligned.

My code below and on [codepen](https://codepen.io/lnreddy2k7/pen/KKwZPez?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=388d072969bc3574273ceb24199d83c28a81c70a-1578200181-0-AQDCU4a6xKdSlFOa6U-nqGzPIine2wi5gtPmN251MYOngb2-_bgWwbOyEMjFck-piLAI00h3dwi5SvK4BV7QKyT5u_R2FfFAlha6Y8rRWjHCOZBItImMgAYbx6YrfrNhnVkt_KJb1n8q_CB0LdyB6-wlWRpTzO5KEpaKI7swr_4dynUBK7NlLyeJy24fhZV0ev6BX670WvFRQ9qVBsSANdOOl5LhHeYbekH5CMinH0147gjY_AYDRIaYXQEUzcT7FwDL2ELnVPPZ8CQXIpL4M3XzWKh-h2ljrDu0UEjvzUY8N0rdxpKyKkaRN_tJUgMyCDWpkZTjbdFXdtIUp2QXINqA94HZSoyBEP8q1KSrVLuW).

```
var barOptions_stacked = {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  },
  hover: {
    animationDuration: 0
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        display: false,
        stepSize: 30
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: false
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: true
      },
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: "y0",
      weight: 1,
      position: "left",
      labels: ["Rohit", "Rohit", "Kohli", "Nair", "kohli"],
      display: true,
      barThickness: 8,
      maxBarThickness: 10,
      barPercentage: 0.4,
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: true,
        beginAtZero: false,
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        fontSize: 14
      }
    }, {
      id: "y1",
      position: "right",
      type: 'category',
      stacked: true,
      labels: ["Dhawan", "Kohli", "Nair", "Kohli", "Jadeja"],
      barThickness: 8,
      maxBarThickness: 10,
      barPercentage: 0.4,
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: true,
        beginAtZero: false,
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        fontSize: 14
      }
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("ps-chart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: [-20, -10, -45, -5, -35],
        yAxisID: 'y0',
        backgroundColor: "#21618C",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(50,90,100,1)"
      },
      {
        data: [30, 5, 20, 45, 50],
        yAxisID: 'y1',
        backgroundColor: "#85C1E9",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(140,85,100,1)"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: barOptions_stacked
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/lnreddy2k7/pen/KKwZPez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you add `offset: true` to both your yAxes.

Personal note: It would be much easier to understand your code if you either combine the code you need for both yAxes or if you would use the properties which you use in one axis in both axes. In your code one yAxis has some properties, the other yAxis has others...

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much..it worked perfect and as suggested by you..used same properties for both y axes.

Comment: @user12654921 If you're happy with the solution, please consider accepting this answer so this question is completed.